# new database sql developer

Tags: sql

I am taking a class and having trouble starting a new database in SQL Developer. There is a connection for our class that we have been using but the teacher said not to delete the tables already there. So to start a new database do I need to make a new connection or is there a way to create a new one in the existing connection without disturbing the already existing database?

Comment: Ask your teacher perhaps? I  doubt he wants you to create a new database instance (though who knows). New user, possibly, depending on what privileges you have on the already existing connection... Or who knows what else.

Comment: I suppose your teacher wants you to add your tables to the already existing tables in the same database. But, that is just guessing. Your teacher knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the SQL Server Management Studio?  You can have many databases on one connection.  To create a new database, simply right click on the "Databases" object and select "New Database"  The new database will not interfere with the existing one.